# send back slash character in json, response code 500

Tags: java, json, backslash

I am trying to send a message via JSONObject over http.

```
JSONObject s=new JSONObject();
s.put("addresses", sno);
s.put("message",message);
s.put("senderName",shortcode);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.write( s.toJSONString());
wr.flush();
// Get the response
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Message is like:

```
String message= “amount1\\KB  \n  amount2\\KB”
```

Expected received message:

```
amount1\KB

amount2\KB
```

Now problem is http server returns me reponse code 500. And cause exception at line 9.
Note: Problem area is String portion \KB  if String would not be containing this back slash everything goes fine.

I had tried:

```
message = message.replaceAll("\\\\", "&#92;");

message = message.replaceAll("\\\\", "%5C");
```

it do not caused my any exception but the received message was as following:

```
amount1&#92;KB

amount2&#92;KB
```

and

```
amount1%5CKB

amount2%5CKB
```

`JSONObject.escape(message)` also didn’t work.

Comment: You can use the built-in formatting for code snippets.

Comment: its :message = message.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\");

message = message.replaceAll("\\\\", "%5C");

Answer (score 0):

Well from that you've written why you just replace back %5C with \ before your show your response?